# dispatch is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, dispatch

i am new to redux and i'm trying to dispatch an action from inside a function but it says "dispatch is not defined no-undef". Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getYear} from '../actions/getYearAction';
import {requestYear} from '../actions';

class SigninForm extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      car :{
        year: '',
        brand:[],
      }
    }
  }

  getYear(){
    return this.props.year.map( (year, id) => {
      return(
        <option value={year} key={id}>{year}</option>
      )
    })
  }

    handleSelection(e){
      dispatch(requestYear( e.target.value ));
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <select onChange = {this.handleSelection.bind(this)}>
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>--YEAR--</option>
          {this.getYear()}
          </select><br/>
          <select>
            <option value='' selected disabled>-Brand-</option>

          </select>
          <button type='submit'>Add</button>
          {this.props.value}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    year: state.year
  }
}
export default connect( mapStateToProps)(SigninForm);
```

i have to make an api call with the year selected from saga but i don't know how to do it.

here's my action

```
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions';

export const REQUEST_YEAR = 'REQUEST_YEAR';
export const requestYear = createAction(REQUEST_YEAR);
```

Please help me
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`dispatch` is a prop just like your other props, you need to call it with `this.props.dispatch`.

Also it's advisable to only pass in the actions that you want to call as props:

```
handleSelection(e) {
  this.props.requestYear( e.target.value );
}

...

export default connect( mapStateToProps, { requestYear })(SigninForm);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
Can you also tell me how do i execute sth from saga after taking the action?

Comment: What do you want to execute? An API call? That's a main use case for redux-saga, you can check the docs for it.

Comment: Thanks! Adding dispatch as this.props.dispatch() fixed my issue.